# docx4j convert w:numPr convert to <ul>?

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

Does docx4j conversion to html support converting w:numPr elements to an html list?

Attempting to have roundtrip html->docx->html.  Experiencing a problem on the return from docx->html - the w:numPr become p and not converted back to the original ul.

For testing, I created a new docx, added a bullet list and converted it to html

Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);

Creates p elements rather than ul.  Does docx4j support creation of  from w:numPr rather than p?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, docx4j doesn't current convert numbered paragraphs into HTML list items.

It would be fairly straightforward to do that, but a bit more effort to wrap the list items in appropriate ol or ul elements.

**UPDATE**

[This commit](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/44a7680f7bb1e2d60969cb7539f572d17884823f) adds ol or ul elements and list items, provided you set:

```
    SdtWriter.registerTagHandler("HTML_ELEMENT", new SdtToListSdtTagHandler());
```

and are using XSL for the output method.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason!  What would the most straightforward way be to implement this?

Comment: As a minor aside, wouldn't a numbered paragraph be better served by being converted to an entry within an `<ol>` element rather than a `<ul>`?

Comment: When I said "numbered" I mean using numId (ie numbering part) which encompasses both bullets (ul) and numbering (ol).

Comment: Just updated to the latest, will be testing it out tomorrow.  Thanks, this is another great addition to docx4j!

Comment: Hi Jason, lists are now properly being created in the conversion from html->docx, however the conversion of docx->html is still creating <p> elements.